# how can i arrange array like this

Tags: php, arrays, minesweeper

I have array like below:

$matrix = array(1, 2, 1,1, 2, 1,1, 1, 1);

how can I get array like below?

```
//OUTPUT:
minesweeper(matrix) = [[1, 2, 1],
                       [2, 1, 1],
                       [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk`

```
$matrix = array(1, 2, 1,1, 2, 1,1, 1, 1);
$res = array_chunk($matrix,3);
print_r($res);
```

[Live working example](https://3v4l.org/5dA9F)